# Acer Aspire A515-51 Ubuntu Install not recognizing hard drive only seeing flash drive and freezes

Tags: boot, laptop, acer, usb-installation, aspire

I am having a problem installing ANY Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire A515-51. I have tried multiple things including disabling secure boot, Legacy, UEFI, etc. Every time I go through the install process the Ubuntu Install does not recognize my HDD and only sees my "flash drive" i.e dev/sba (or whatever it says) and every time I try to add a partition it freezes. I believe this is because that it is trying to add a partition to a "mounted" flash drive and not the hard drive. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have tried everything I have found on a variety of forums.

Also I don't want to dual boot. I want to wipe windows 10 completely off and just run Ubuntu as I have another machine that runs 10. I just want my laptop to run Ubuntu and be able to boot Kali Linux from USB drive when I need it to.